# What is CTime (Is there any) 32bit analog?

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I found there is ctime and _ctime_32 in the `<time.h>` but also ctime is not CTime. Is there CTime 32 bit analog? Or maybe something alike 32bit CTime with __time32_t. I've got compatibility troubles using 64bit versions.

ok maybe I don't need CTime at all, I'm recieving __time32_t and using it to provide variant time :

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
   CTime tmp =  pCurPar[pot->numSubsection].SysTime;
      tmp.GetAsSystemTime( st );
    SystemTimeToVariantTime(&st,&pot->Value.date);
```

but I think

```
CTime tmp =  pCurPar[pot->numSubsection].SysTime;
```

is not correct convert because my .SysTime is __time32_t and CTime is using 64bit version.

even I've got one situation when I need to provide it as time32_t but with `pot->Value.intVal = DayRec[pot->numSubsection].startTime.GetTime();` Iv'e got warning `Warning  3   warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__time64_t' to 'INT', possible loss of data`

Comment: What exactly is your "troubles"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have Visual Studio Express and can't test it, but shouldn't the compiler automatically convert the 32-bit type to the 64-bit type? Doing it the other way around will cause a warning about loosing precision, but 32-to-64 bit conversions shouldn't be a problem. Test it, and come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: So yes, you are right. But I have a situation when I need to provide in __time32_t format.

Comment: @nCdy You can add an explicit cast to `__time32_t` get rid of the warnings, but I recommend you also add a comment saying why you do the cast. And maybe a note saying it won't work after January 18 2038. :)